# Automatic table of contents entry from environment

Tags: table-of-contents, environments

I have created an environment to be used in creating examples in my text. The class is one specified by the publisher Wiley, basically a book.

The environment currently takes the name of the example as an argument and displays, in the text, e.g. "Example section.forinstancecounter 'Text in first argument'" and then formats the following text a little different from the surrounding text to set it off. I would like the "Example section.forinstancecounter 'Text in first argument'" to appear in the table of contents automatically.

In other words I wish my environment to be treated the same as other sections of the same level as my example (`subsection`).

Is this a hard thing to do?

The environment:

```
\newcounter{forinstancecounter}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theforinstancecounter}{\thechapter.\arabic{forinstancecounter}}
\newenvironment{forinstance}[1]{
\begin{quote}
  \refstepcounter{forinstancecounter}
  \textbf{Example \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{forinstancecounter}\quad #1}
  \quad
}{
\end{quote}
}
```

Thank you,
Bull

Comment: Just to be clear: An example - `forinstance` - is similar to a `\subsection` in the ToC? What happens what you have an example inside a `\section`? Or will that never happen?

Comment: Welcome! `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{<entry>}` ?

Answer (score 2):

Unsure if this is wanted: A list of 'For instances'?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listofforinstancename}{List of Examples}
\newlistof[chapter]{forinstancecounter}{exa}{\listofforinstancename}

%\newcounter{forinstancecounter}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theforinstancecounter}{\thechapter.\arabic{forinstancecounter}}
\newenvironment{forinstance}[1]{
\begin{quote}
  \refstepcounter{forinstancecounter}
  \textbf{Example \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{forinstancecounter}\quad #1}
  \addcontentsline{exa}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\theforinstancecounter~}#1}
  \quad
}{
\end{quote}
}

\begin{document}
\listofforinstancecounter
\chapter{My first chapter}
\begin{forinstance}{A title}
Hello World
\end{forinstance}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. cfr, the addcontentsline requires me to add the text each time it's invoked, right? I wanted it to be automatic. Christian's suggestion is not exactly what I wanted but may be better. It works fine, except that now the headings 'Contents' (of the table of contents) and 'List of Examples' are in huge font. I didn't see anything in your code that would change that for only those two headings. There could be interactions with Wiley's style however.

Comment: @BullDurham: I don't have the Wiley style, but the font size can be changed with `tocloft` -- you did not gave much information really ;-)